# Test website with million concurrent connections

Tags: performance, web, load, load-testing

I have a website it is under construction. I need to test the website performance when the concurrent connections. Is there any tool for generate the thousands of concurrent connection virtually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

opensourcetesting.org website gives the [list of 54 performance testing tools](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php) as for the moment.

The most powerful of existing free and open source tools are:

- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

I believe that [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) guide will help you to choose the right option.